# Remove a list inside a list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to remove the list [1,2,3] inside the outer list.
I tried `or isinstance(item, list)` but that didn't work, the nested list was still there.

```
messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, [1, 2, 3]]

# Your code goes below here
messy_list.pop(3)
messy_list.insert(0,1)

for item in messy_list:
    if isinstance(item, str) or isinstance(item, bool):
        messy_list.remove(item)

messy_list.pop(-1)

print(messy_list)
```

I would like to know if there wasn't a better way to check if there's a list inside the list, and then remove from the outer list, instead of having to hardcode it with .pop(-1)

Comment: Perhaps a list comprehension `messy_list = [i for i in messy_list if not isinstance(i,list)]`

Comment: @Dark you beat me to it, want to make it an answer?

Comment: `or isinstance(item, list)` worked for me, so maybe it was something else? btw, it's not recommended to do operations on the list that you loop over, use a copy instead, one way is `for item in messy_list[:]:` or go with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will remove ALL inner lists:

```
messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, [1, 2, 3]] 

cleaned = [item for item in messy_list if not isinstance(item,list)]

print(cleaned)
```

I am using a list comprehension that inspects all `item`s of your `messy_list`  and only adds it to the resulting new list if it is not a list itself.

Answer (score -1):

We can remove a list inside a list same way like we remove the single list, just provide the reference of the list object to the del function.

```
del(list_object).
```

for example :-

```
a = [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
del(a[3])
```

after this a will look like.

```
[1, 2, 3]
```